# CKeditor Image2 plugin not showing advance tab?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

We are using CKeditor4 and added image2 plugin but image2 does not contain advanced tab. To enable the advanced tab in image dialogue I added "Advanced Tab for Dialog plugin" and added "dialogadvtab" in extraPlugins even after all these its not working.

```
  var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'];
 if (editor) { editor.destroy(true); }
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    extraPlugins: 'dialogadvtab,uploadimage,image2',
    resize_enabled: 'false',
    removePlugins: 'elementspath',
    forcePasteAsPlainText : true,
    enterMode : CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
    shiftEnterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_P,
    dialog_noConfirmCancel : true,
    linkShowAdvancedTab : false,
    linkShowTargetTab : false,
    allowedContent:true,  
 });
```

Comment: The advanced tab is not available for `image2` plugin. Below is the answer from one of CKEditor developers: There are no plans to work on advanced tabs for both - image2 itself and image2's links. If a developer needs additional image or link settings, which can't be applied using stylesheets (which is the recommended way), then she/he must extend the image2 plugin. This can be done using the dialog and widget APIs.